# heroku session-affinity for apps with no cookie support

Tags: heroku, sticky-session, session-affinity

[Heroku session affinity](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/session-affinity) mentions that sticky session is achieved by passing down a cookie. But we use heroku for TV apps where there is no cookie support. Sticky session is very important to us. Does anyone know if sticky session on heroku can be achieved without cookie support?